# Chat link in top bar missing?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

This morning, I sit at my desk, almost spill my coffee, get settled and open firefox 5.0.1 and what do I see? The chat link is missing. WTF mate, like my morning could have started any worse?

[image]

Comment: I usually go through Meta and click on The Comms Room from there. Different path, same result.

Answer (score 6):

See [this Meta report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/eeeek-where-did-the-chat-top-navigation-link-go) for details, but to summarize:

To help promote the visibility of blog posts, **during the first 24 hours after a new post is added to your site's blog, it will replace the chat link in the header**. Afterward, it will be back to business as usual.

In Server Fault's case, you have two blogs. The main Server Fault blog is linked on the main site, while our general Stack Exchange blog is linked on your Meta site.

Comment: Wow, that's terrible. Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: Which brings up the other issue that @MarkM has pointed out [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101898/chat-side-bar-not-showing-up-on-server-fault) - we seem to be lacking our right-side chat box.